# EmguCv EigenObjectRecognizer creating instance

Tags: c#, emgucv

My application gets closed when it reaches at creating the recognizer object of EigenObjectRecognizer class without giving any error or warning , am I passing wrong parameters or there is some other problem ? Here is my code

```
 string[] allFaces = Directory.GetFiles(savepath);
            if (allFaces != null)
            {


                Image<Gray, Byte>[] trainingImages = new Image<Gray, Byte>[allFaces.Length];
                string[] labels = new String[allFaces.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < allFaces.Length; i++)
                {
                    trainingImages[i]  = new Image<Gray, byte>(new Bitmap(allFaces[i]));
                    labels[i] = allFaces[i].Substring(allFaces[i].LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
                }


                MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(allFaces.Length, 0.001);

                EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                   trainingImages,
                   labels,
                   1000,
                     ref termCrit);



                Image<Gray, Byte> testImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(@"C:\..test\1");

                string label = recognizer.Recognize(testImage).Label;
                MessageBox.Show(label);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by getting an error from raw run of the compiled exe which gave an error of input of not same size from opencv instead of emgucv . When I looked at my training images they were of different size. Hope it helps others